# Pegar só um item de uma lista ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como eu faço para pegar somente um item de uma lista? por exemplo:

tenho uma classe chamada `Cliente`, meu cliente tem uma coleção de `Contatos`

```
Public class Cliente
{
public Int Id {get ;set;}

public Icollection<Contatos> Contato {get ;set }
}
```

na minha view, eu trago o cliente ja com os contatos incluso, o que eu quero saber é se te como eu pegar somente um item dessa lista. mesmo que seja o primeiro, cadastrado.

```
@foreach(cliente in Model)
{
<td>@item.Id</td>
<td>contatos // aqui quero pegar só um contato da coleção<td>
}
```

Comment: mas qual o critério? precisa saber qual quer, o primeiro? `Model.FirstOrDefault()`, o cliente com Id 3? `Model.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 3)`.... são exemplos, dê mais detalhes

Comment: Não seria `Model.Contatos.FirtOrDefault` ? quero pegar o primeiro item da lista

Comment: sim isso mesmo, eu coloquei só exemplos. Se for só o primeiro isso já resolve, ou se tiver certeza que a lista está preenchida, `First()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amigo vc pode fazer de duas maneiras, são essas que eu conheço e aplico nas soluções aqui:

1° opção:

```
<label>Categoria</label>
<select asp-for="Establishment.Id_Category" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Category,"idCategory","CategoryName"))" id="category" class="form-control" required>
<option selected disabled>Categoria</option>
</select>
```

2° opção

```
<label for="categoria">Categoria*</label>
<select id="categoria" name="categoria" class="form-control">
 <option selected>Selecione uma Categoria</option>
 @foreach (var C in ViewBag.ListaCategoria)
 {
   <option value="@(C.idCategoria)">@(C.nomeCategoria)</option>
 }
 </select>
```

ambos os exemplos fornecem uma lista de categorias para o cliente, e quando o usuário seleciona uma categoria, o que vai para o servidor é o ID dessa categoria, o ID seria um identificador da categoria no banco de dados para fazer o relacionamento entre tabelas e tal...

no seu caso o que importa para vc é o value, é nele que vc coloca aquilo que pode identificar todo o dado, se for fazer uma busca no bd, pode ser um ID por exemplo...